# matplotlib: how to plot concentric circles at a given set of radii

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot concentric circles at a given set of distances away from a source.  The first thing I tried to do was draw an arc on polar plot, as this seemed like a logical substep:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot([1.0,1.5], [5,5], color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

The first problem I'm having is that this draws a straight line rather than an arc:

[image: polar with straight line]

So the subquestion might be *how do I draw an arc, in this case a 360 degree arc, at a given radius on a polar plot?*.  On the other hand, there might be a better solution altogether, perhaps one that doesn't involve a polar plot.  Ultimately, as per the title, my objective is to draw concentric circles at a set of radii around a centre source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easy, use it to make shooting targets all the time.:

```
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100), np.ones(100)*5, color='r', linestyle='-')
```

Just think of how you define a circle in a polar axis? Need two things, angle and radius. Those are `np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)` and `np.ones(100)*5` here. If you just need a arc, change the first argument to something less than 0 to 2pi. And change the 2nd argument accordingly.

[image]
There are other ways to do this. `plot()` creates `.lines.Line2D object` objects, if you want `.collections.PathCollection object` instead of Line2D:

```
ax.scatter(1, 0, s=100000, facecolors='none')
```

Or you want to make `patch`es:

```
ax.bar(0, 5, 2*np.pi, bottom=0.0, facecolor='None') #need to modified the edge lines or won't look right
```

Comment: Seems like a fair solution.  I take it this actually works by drawing a large number (100) of small straight line segments, rather than an arc per se?  It probably won't present an issue in practice, though if a method for drawing arcs specifically does or doesn't exist that would be good to know.

Comment: @Bryce Thomas, if you were to plot `y=sin(x)` in Cartesian coordinate system, what will you do in `matplotlib`, pretty much the same thing right? Now if you hate that, there are other ways to do it that I just added.